# django complex datamodel

Tags: sql, django, database, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating a small Django project which show stats collected from twitter data
for example my tables are

```
hashDetails
---------------------------------------------
id   hashname tweetPosted  trendDate  userid
---------------------------------------------
1    #abc       44        2-2-2016    @xyz
2    #abc       55        2-2-2016    @qwer
3    #xcs       55        3-2-2016    @qwer
4    #xcs       55        4-2-2016    @qwer
---------------------------------------------

userDetails
----------------------------------------------
id    userid     profileImage   profileImage
----------------------------------------------
1     @xyz        image2.jpg     www.abc.com
2     @qwer       image3.jpg     www.xadf.com
----------------------------------------------
```

for this if i create models.py

```
class userDetails(models.Model):
    userid= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profileImage= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    profileImage= models.CharField(max_length=30)

class hashDetails(models.Model):
    hashname= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    tweetPosted= models.IntegerField()
    trendDate= models.DateTimeField()
    userid = models.ForeignKey(userDetails, to_field ='userid')
```

but i don't wanna make userid unique cause

i want something like i can enter data in both table manually 
and when i query in my view it will search result from both table
example 
if i want all trends by @xyz
or if i want list of all users who did #abc trend 
or if i want result of all trends in specific date

in short i want both table to behave like one 
I can't use userid as unique my daily data will be about 20MB so you can assume its difficult to find ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution of my problem and its working for me
i just create normal 2 model without foreignkey or any relation
and define my function in views.py 
and got my result what i want

```
def teamdetail(request,test_id):
    hashd = hashDetails.objects.get(hashname=test_id)
    userd=  userDetails.objects.all()
    context = {'hashinfo': hashd, 'username':userd}
    return render(request,'test/hashDetails.html',context)
```